# Electron/Chromium: how to set about:flags value with command line?

Tags: command-line, electron, lazy-loading

I know that I can toggle lazy image loading by loading URL `chrome://flags/#enable-lazy-image-loading` and pressing the toggle. Is there a way to pass the required value (true or false) using command line flags?

I'm currently trying to figure out this for an Electron app but I would like to find a more generic solution. If a single command line option would work for Electron, Chromium and Google Chrome, it would be perfect.

Comment: It seems that for Chrome, one could write pre-made configuration file `Local State` (notice the spelling: with space and title case) in the user profile directory with suitable config. For example, disabling smooth scrolling would be  something like `browser.enabled_labs_experiments.push("smooth-scrolling@2")` using JSON syntax. I'm pretty sure that the index (`@2` here) is not defined and isn't probably stable. Electron doesn't seem to pick up this file, though.